# viewWillAppear alternative for custom UILabel, UIButton classes

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any function that is similar to viewWillAppear() for UIIbutton classes?
All these functions below are called only once

> prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
>
> awakeFromNib()
>
> init()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So not exactly like a viewWillAppear, No.

This is because these are fundamentally different aspects of the architecture. One is usually the manager(a viewController), and the other always is a minion(UIView).
Their lifecycles are naturally different.

But if you want to perform a change in your custom view, whether a UIButton or any other UIView subclass, what you can do to reset is to use the method `setNeedsLayout()`.

From the apple docs

> Call this method on your application’s main thread when you want to
>   adjust the layout of a view’s subviews. This method makes a note of
>   the request and returns immediately. Because this method does not
>   force an immediate update, but instead waits for the next update
>   cycle, you can use it to invalidate the layout of multiple views
>   before any of those views are updated. This behavior allows you to
>   consolidate all of your layout updates to one update cycle, which is
>   usually better for performance.
>   Blockquote

You should perform further operations on the setting of the view by overriding 
the `layoutSubviews()` method

Again, from the docs

> Subclasses can override this method as needed to perform more precise
>   layout of their subviews. You should override this method only if the
>   autoresizing and constraint-based behaviors of the subviews do not
>   offer the behavior you want. You can use your implementation to set
>   the frame rectangles of your subviews directly. You should not call
>   this method directly. If you want to force a layout update, call the
>   setNeedsLayout() method instead to do so prior to the next drawing
>   update. If you want to update the layout of your views immediately,
>   call the layoutIfNeeded() method.

Hope I have been clear in the explanation.

You can also post your exact situation with code for more clarity and answers.

Comment: your answer works well for UIButton custom classes. For some odd reasons the UILabels don't change their text color. anyway, thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 1):

**There is no strait way to do it:** UILabel, UIButton haven't such functions because they are inherited from UIControl -> UIView -> UIResponder these classes haven't such functionality.

**What you can to do:** in your main controller which contains buttons and labels you can call custom method at `viewWillAppear` which will update content on your custom elements.

PS. Elements you can organize like an array or also check super views and based on protocol / class call your custom method.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Abhishek Arora, I was able to change the UILabel's textColor this way.

```
     override func setNeedsLayout() {
       tintColor = .clear
    }



     override func tintColorDidChange() {

     print("TINT COLOR DID CHANGE")
       textColor = .blue

              }
}
```